# SQL avoiding Multipart Identifier on subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

Using SQLExpress 2017

I have some products distributed over warehouses and I would like to see how many items would need to be stocked to meet the sales of a given period.

```
Need pr. warehouse = Stock - CustomerOrders + SupplierOrders - SumOfSalesInPeriod
```

Now I would like to sum that up for each product, but I am no interested in warehouses where the need is already met, so I only want the negative values but I have some trouble getting it to work as I am met with Multipart Identifier errors.
Using the distinct keyword also makes me think that I am doing too many calculations and there must be a better way of doing this.

```
declare @fromDate date = '1900-01-01 12:00:00';
declare @toDate date = '3000-01-01 12:00:00';

select *,
    balance =  
        (select 
            turn = sum(TurnOver)
        from (
        select 
            WarehouseStocks.Id,
            TurnOver = WarehouseStocks.Qty 
                        - WarehouseStocks.OrderedByCustomersQty 
                        + WarehouseStocks.OrderedFromSuppliersQty 
                        - isnull((select Sum(StockEntries.Qty) 
                                    from StockEntries 
                                    where 
                                        StockEntries.Type = 1 
                                        and StockEntries.ProductId = WarehouseStocks.Id 
                                        and WarehouseStocks.WarehouseId = StockEntries.WarehouseId 
                                        and StockEntries.Date >= @fromDate 
                                        and StockEntries.Date <= @toDate), 0) 
        from WarehouseStocks) Product where TurnOver < 0
        group by Product.Id) tp where Products.Id = tp.Id)
from Products
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some product specific functionality used.)

Comment: SqlExpress 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite this using CTE instead, to break it down and make the query more readable. Something like this:

```
declare @fromDate date = '1900-01-01 12:00:00';
declare @toDate date = '3000-01-01 12:00:00';

;with SE 
as
(
    select Sum(StockEntries.Qty) as SumStockEnties , StockEntries.ProductId, StockEntries.WarehouseId 
    from StockEntries 
    where 
        StockEntries.Type = 1 
        and StockEntries.Date >= @fromDate 
        and StockEntries.Date <= @toDate
    group by StockEntries.ProductId, StockEntries.WarehouseId 
),
TP
as
(
    Select WS.Id, WS.Qty - WS.OrderedByCustomersQty + WS.OrderedFromSuppliersQty - isnulle(SE.SumStockEnties, 0) as TurnOver
    from WarehouseStocks as WS
         left join SE
         on  SE.ProductId = WS.Id
          and SE.WarehouseId = WS.WarehouseId 
)
Select *
from TP 
    inner join Products as PR
    on PR.id = TP.id
Where PR.TurnOver < 0
```